# Checking presense of a point in multiple rectangles usinq LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a square shape like this that is devided to 9 rectangles:

[image]

So I want to instead of making a long list of like this:

```
if(rectForward.Contains(touchPoint))
{
   return rectForward;
}
else if(rectForwardRight.Contains(touchPoint))
{
    return rectForwardRight;
}
//and so on!
```

Quickly check with a linq query to see which `Rectangle` contains the `Point` touchPoint.

Well I could use the time that I spend on this question to write the if/else stuff but I would like to see how it goes with `linq`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try storing all your rectangles in a collection, then it becomes trivial to iterate over them:

```
return myRectangles.FirstOrDefault(rect => rect.Contains(touchPoint))
```

Depending on what you want to do if the point is *not* contained in any of them, you may want to use `First` only (which would throw an exception if the point isn't contained by any of them); `FirstOrDefault` will (assuming you're using the `System.Windows.Rect` class) return a default `Rect` (located at `0,0` with `0` size) so that may be difficult to check for.

If you don't want to store the rectangles in a collection, you can write a simple helper method to iterate over them in sequence and leverage that when you wish:

```
private IEnumerable<Rect> GetSections()
{
    yield return rectForward;
    yield return rectForwardRight;
    yield return rectRight;
    ...
}
```

To which your Linq call would use:

```
return GetSections().FirstOrDefault(rect => rect.Contains(touchPoint))
```